# How to put a transparent image over everything

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, transparency

I am creating a program for Ubuntu which should be able to display an image (probably animated) over the top of all windows, although if the image is over the top of a button on an application, it shouldn't prevent you from pressing that button, or interacting with anything else on the screen.

I saw that there was already a question asking about almost the same thing here [Is there a way to superimpose a transparent image over everything that is displayed on screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96807/is-there-a-way-to-superimpose-a-transparent-image-over-everything-that-is-displa), although I see that that one was closed for some reason and did not receive any answers, so I am asking again. How could this be achieved? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Comment: Here's an answer from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914785/how-to-click-through-gtk-window)

Comment: @hbdgaf: And how could I make this 'gtk window' go over everything including the top bar with the "Activities Overview" button on it etc?

Comment: Absolute position, borderless, and sizing.  The hard part is clicking through the window, so that's the answer I found you.